# Is Apple's PLIST an open standard?

Tags: xml, macos, plist

I've searched Google for awhile now, and I can't seem to find anything, and I'm wondering because I have hopes of creating my own OS and plist seems like a great format. (I know it'll never amount to anything, but please stay on topic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GnuStep](http://www.gnustep.org/) uses it so it must be ok

**edit**
The above answer was provided, and accepted, back in January, but four months later MarcusJ has *unaccepted* it for no apparent reason than that the question has been downvoted a number of times (wrongly in my opinion).

To nudge the answer back into acceptancy I offer the following evidence:

http://opensource.apple.com/plist/mac-os-x-108.plist

A list of open source apple projects, provided in... plist format

http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2004/Dec/msg00051.html

an IANAL answer to the question: **license of the plist format**

Bear in mind that none of this sort of thing is certain until tested in court. For more surety, I suggest contacting the GnuStep people (who will have thought about this)  or stir the hornet's nest with an email to Tim Cook...

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 styles of property list, xml, binary and old style from the old NeXT days and it's still working. I usually prefer old style for human read/writability though it isn't as human friendly as LDAP. In short, every format should just work for you. It isn't something that could easily change unless somebody want to seriously break some backward compatibilities.

Comment: Idk about the old style, becuase I'm only familiar with plutil's xml, binary, and json, but that sounds intresting. I was thinking about using the binary one because it would produce smaller files that were easier to parse.

Comment: It looks like this http://svn.gna.org/svn/gnustep/apps/projectcenter/trunk/Resources/Info-gnustep.plist